# Probability law

Tags: probability

$X$ random variable discrete, defined on $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{N}^*$

Find conditions on $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}^2$ so that : $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\left \{ \frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b} \text{ if } 1\leq k\leq ab \text{ else } 0\right\}$  define a probability law.
I tried to calculate the $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N P(X=k)=1$
and I found $\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)\cdot N =1$, is that correct ?
But I need a relation without $N$
any ideas?

Comment: I think, the general idea behind MSE is that you should provide some context, your own attempts, anything that won't look like you are asking MSE community to do the homework for you.

Comment: my attempt: I tried to calculate the sum (P(X=k)) = 1 that gives me (1/a-1b)*n=1

Comment: Update the question with your attempts, please.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers or any reals?

Comment: a,b integers not nulls

Comment: Right, technically you are progressing alright. All that is left is to show that $N=a\cdot b$, do you agree?

Comment: i don't agree, I need conditions on a,b
I think that we should have two cases if P=0 and the second case P=1/a-1/b

Comment: But if $k> a\cdot b$ then $P(X=k)=0$, so you have $$1=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a\cdot b} P(X=k)=a\cdot b \cdot \left(\frac{1}{a} -\frac{1}{b}\right)=b-a$$ and finally $b-a=1$. Right?

Comment: correct.Yes, did you find it easily ?

Comment: I think I solved it before :) ... some 25 years ago, when I studied probability distributions at Uni.

Comment: ah ok, and what do you suggest to find the rapartition's function of X?

Comment: Come on, you can do it $P(X\leq x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k\leq x} P(X=k)$.

Comment: i replaced x by ab and i found b-a in the first case and 0 then

Comment: It should be a function of $x$ and you have $2$ cases for $x\leq ab$ and $x > ab$.

Comment: so that means the two values of the function are 1 and 0

Comment: sorry i found x/ab if x inf ab and 0 then